# Replace NA by value from same data table with matching category in other column

Tags: r

I have the following data table:

```
class <- c(NA, "red", NA, "yellow", NA, NA, NA)
food <- c("apple", "apple", "onion", "banana", "banana", "banana", "onion")
amount <- 1:length(class)
dt <- data.table(class, food, amount)
```

Output:

```
    class   food amount
1:   <NA>  apple      1
2:    red  apple      2
3:   <NA>  onion      3
4: yellow banana      4
5:   <NA> banana      5
6:   <NA> banana      6
7:   <NA>  onion      7
```

I want to replace the `NAs` in `class`. The replacement should be the `class` category of a matching `food` category.

Desired output:

```
    class   food amount
1:    red  apple      1
2:    red  apple      2
3:   <NA>  onion      3
4: yellow banana      4
5: yellow banana      5
6: yellow banana      6
7:   <NA>  onion      7
```

I tried several approaches with sorting the data according to `food` and `class`, and then using `zoo::na.locf`.
`merge` would work, but I want to avoid it due to renaming/deletion of columns, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me :)

`dt[, class := class[!is.na(class)][1], by=food]`

`by=food` groups it by food, `class[!is.na(class)][1]` filters to all the non NA values in the class column and picks the first it finds.

Then `class :=` is assigning it back to the original column

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to add it might be a good idea to test if multiple values exist in `class` variable eg `testthat::expect_false(any(dt[, uniqueN(class[!is.na(class)]), by=food][, V1 > 1]))`. `uniqueN` finds number of cases of `class`, by `food` and then use `testthat` package to check for any with more than 1 case. Will error the script if eg you get "green" and "red" class values for food="apple" as then your solution may need more thought. Ignore this if you're example is simple and you don't need to worry about multiple classes popping up :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try something like below

```
dt[,class := zoo::na.locf(class),by = food]
```

or

```
dt[, class := unique(na.omit(class)), by=food]
```

such that

```
> dt
    class   food amount
1:    red  apple      1
2:    red  apple      2
3:   <NA>  onion      3
4: yellow banana      4
5: yellow banana      5
6: yellow banana      6
7:   <NA>  onion      7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R option.

```
dt <- transform(dt, class=ave(class, food, FUN=function(x) 
        ifelse(!all(is.na(x)), rep(x[!is.na(x)], length(x)), x)))
dt
#     class   food amount
# 1:    red  apple      1
# 2:    red  apple      2
# 3:   <NA>  onion      3
# 4: yellow banana      4
# 5: yellow banana      5
# 6: yellow banana      6
# 7:   <NA>  onion      7
```